# Convert 2 pairs in array to getassociative array

Tags: php, arrays

The title of this questions sounds a bit confusing, but I don't know how I should call it, so I will explain it further:

For example I got the following array:

```
 [0]=> "id" [1]=> "5" [2]=> "value" [3]=> "8"
```

And so on, this array could be endless, but the number of content is even.
Now I want to have this array converted into an associative array where on pair is index => value. Like this:

```
[id] = "5" [value] = "8"
```

I thought about, that I foreach the array twice: first I set the indexes if count is odd and second I reset index and set the value if count is even. But there must be a better approach to do this.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: when you say endless, do you mean endless properties like "size", "color" or the same two properties above recurring again and again?

Comment: no, I meant other properties. I'm aware that I can't use the same index for multiple entries :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array = array("id", "5", "value", "8");
$new_array = array();

for ($i = 1; $i < count($array); $i+=2) {
  $new_array[$array[$i - 1]] = $array[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code should serve your purpose:

```
$arr = array("id", "5", "value", "8");
$size = sizeof($arr);
$_arr = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i+=2){
$_arr[$arr[$i]] = $arr[$i+1];
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/107831)

Comment: Thanks, your approach is like the answer from faintsignal, but I'm getting an error message with: undefined index, cause it's looking in the future with the + 1 and at the end there is no index available. But nice and fast answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not a multidimensional array?

```
$arr = array(
    array("id", "5"),
    array("value", "8")
);
```

Comment: Sorry, can't use this, cause I'm not generating the array I need to "convert".